# How do I pop up an image in a separate div on mouse-over using CSS only?

Tags: css, xhtml, popup

I have a small gallery of thumbnails. When I place my mouse pointer over a thumbnail image I'd like to have a full size image pop up in a div in the top right of the screen. I've seen this done using just CSS and I'd like to go down that route rather than use javascript if possible.

Comment: You probably ought to go with Javascript if browser compatibility is important.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Pure CSS Popups2](http://meyerweb.com/eric/css/edge/popups/demo2.html), from the same site that brings us Complexspiral. Note that this example is using actual navigational links as the rolled-over element. If you don't want that, it may cause some stickiness regarding versions of IE.

The basic technique is to stick each image inside a link tag with an actual href (Otherwise some IE versions will neglect :hover)

```
<a href="#">Text <img class="popup" src="pic.gif" /></a>
```

and position it cleverly using absolute position. Hide the image initially

```
a img.popup { display: none }
```

and then on the link rollover, set it up to appear.

```
a:hover img.popup { display: block }
```

That's the basic technique, but there are always going to be major positioning limitations since the image tag dwells inside the link tag. See the link for details; he uses something a little more tricky than display: none to hide the image.

Answer (score 1):

[CSS Playground](http://www.cssplay.co.uk) uses pure CSS for this type of thing, one of the demos is surely to help you and as it's all CSS just view source to learn - you probably want to use the :hover pseudo class but there are limitations to it depending on your browser targeting.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few examples:

- [CSS Image gallery](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/csslibrary/item/css-image-gallery/)
- [Cross Browser Multi-Page Photograph Gallery](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/lightbox.html)
- [A CSS-only Image Gallery: Explained](http://designsignature.co.za/blog/?p=29)
- [A CSS-only Image Gallery: Example](http://www.designsignature.co.za/web.php)

This last one acts upon click. Just to be complete in behaviours.

Answer (score -1):

Eric Meyer's [Pure CSS Popups 2](http://meyerweb.com/eric/css/edge/popups/demo2.html) demo sounds similar enough to what you want.